# Event listener error in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

So I've added click event listeners on some elements and on click I need to add and remove classes.

```
// ind is a list of javascript elements

for(var i=0; i<ind.length; i++){
    ind[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      for(var j=0; j<ind.length; j++){
        ind[j].classList.remove('active');
      }
      ind[i].classList.add('active');
      selectedInd = ind[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error that ind[i] is undefined when I click on any element.
 It works fine when I write it like this -

```
for(var i=0; i<ind.length; i++){
    ind[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      for(var j=0; j<ind.length; j++){
        ind[j].classList.remove('active');
      }
      this.classList.add('active');
      selectedInd = this.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    });
}
```

Why it doesn't work with the first code block. If I use let then it works also.